# `foo.Seconds()` (type time.Duration) error - Cannot use 'd.Step.Seconds()' (type float64) as type time.Duration

Tags: datetime, go

I'm still really new to go...so,

The crux of my issue can be summed up as this: I'm preparing data to be sent off to a remote API which requires this field to be a `time.Duration` type, which I was trying to send as a string type of seconds `###s` and would `time.ParseDuration()` it to seconds, however that was a mistake.

```
type Duration struct {
    Duration time.Duration
    Step     time.Duration
}

// Needs to return a structure containing a duration formatted
// item and an item which is strictly in `seconds` format IE 
// `int` or `float` `+` `"s"`.
func getDuration(pr *PromRequest) (Duration, error) {
    duration, err := time.ParseDuration(pr.TimeRange)
    if err != nil {
        return Duration{}, nil
    }

    timeValue, err := strconv.Atoi(pr.TimeRange[:len(pr.TimeRange)-1])
    if err != nil {
        return Duration{}, err
    }

    // convert day value to day in hours
    step := time.Duration(int64(24*timeValue) * 60 / 14)

    return Duration{
        Duration: duration,
        Step:     step, // <-- should be a time.Duration type...
    }, nil
}

//    \/\/hatever
func getMetricsWithRange(pr *PromRequest) (model.Value, error) {
    d, err := getDuration(pr)
    if err != nil {
        e := fmt.Errorf("unable to translate received time into proper parsed time signature: %s", err)
        fmt.Println(e)
        return nil, err
    }

...
    r := v1.Range{
        Start: time.Now().Add(-d.Duration),
        End:   time.Now(),
        Step:  d.Step.Seconds(),  // <-- error lands here stating it's a float64
    }
...
}
```

** EDIT **

So I think I understand my misunderstanding now. `time.Duration()` returns a time.Duration type on which one can then send through `.Seconds()`, which returns a `float64`.

In the caller, which consumed the returned struct, when I printed the value of the instance variable it would be something NOT `time.Duration`. I needed it to be in seconds as a `time.Duration` type in the form of `###s`, which I learned `time.Duration` won't do. Calling `.Seconds()` on it failed with the error `Cannot use 'd.Step.Seconds()' (type float64) as type time.Duration`

OK, so my misunderstanding came from a few factors. One: I was really tired. Two: I'm new to go and statically typed languages in general. Three: I believed I needed to send `v1.Range.Step` in seconds, which was wrong. I took a look at the receiving code which transforms the `time.Duration` value into seconds itself.

Now, the bigger part of this problem came from the fact that my frontend code was sending a value in days using the letter `d` in the string. `time.ParseDuration()` doesn't handle `d` days so instead of using `days` I thought I would simply pass a time value in seconds.

Turns out, the easiest way to fix this was to simply send `seconds` from the frontend. I was never able to get the go code to work right.

Comment: `1043s` is (or at least looks like) a string: it has a letter `s` in it. You could store that in `string` or `[]byte` but not in any numeric data type. You can take a nanoseconds value and divide it by 1 billion to get seconds, and that's what `func (d Duration) Seconds() float64` in the `time` package does. But you definitely cannot get something ending in the letter `s` if you store it as a floating point or integer number—you'd have to *format* it into a `string` or `[]byte` and add the `s`.

Comment: Your goal is not at all clear to me. Do you want a `time.Duration`, a `string`, or an `int`? You've claimed all three, either directly or indirectly.

Comment: I've attempted to clarify what I was trying to accomplish. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Duration.Seconds()` returns a `float64` value, because the duration value may not be a whole second and it may have decimal digits to represent the exact duration. If the `Step` variable is to be a duration rounded up to the nearest second, use `Duration.Round(time.Second)`:

```
...
Step: Step.Round(time.Second)
```

This will give you a duration that is rounded to a whole second.

If you want to get the seconds value, that's not a duration, that's simply an integer:

```
...
Step: int(Step.Seconds())
```

However, in this case the resulting `Step` is not a duration, but simply an int value giving the number of seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm still struggling with this. I think the crux of my issue can be summed up as this. I'm just preparing data to be sent off to a remote API which requires this field to be a `time.Duration` type *in seconds only*. Apparently, this can't be done?

Comment: @Jim, time.Duration is a duration in nanoseconds and you cannot redefine that. You have to decide between time.Duration and some value in seconds, which as stated in the answer is just a float or an int.

Comment: @Jim, if that remote API uses `time.Duration`, then it cannot get seconds values only, but you can round the duration to exact seconds. If you want to send seconds value, then it cannot be `time.Duration`.